# Retrieving scripted page urls via web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get all of the article link from a web scraped search query, however I don't seem to get any results.

Web page in question: http://www.seek.com.au/jobs/in-australia/#dateRange=999&workType=0&industry=&occupation=&graduateSearch=false&salaryFrom=0&salaryTo=999999&salaryType=annual&advertiserID=&advertiserGroup=&keywords=police+check&page=1&isAreaUnspecified=false&location=&area=&nation=3000&sortMode=Advertiser&searchFrom=quick&searchType=

my approach:
I'm trying to get the ids of articles and then append them to the already known url (http://www.seek.com.au/job/+ id) however there are no ids on my request(python package from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) retrieval, in fact there are no articles at all.

it seems that in this particular case I need to execute the scripts(that generate ids) in some way to get the full data, how could I do that?

maybe there are other ways to retrieve all of the results from this search query?

Comment: Seek is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) paginated; meaning its pages are loaded through javascript. You need a scraping engine which understands and executes javascript. I recommend you become familiar with something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Anyway of keeping this inside Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, download Selenium. There are python [bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Selenium is a web testing automation framework. In effect, by using selenium you are remote controlling a web browser. This is necessary as web browsers have javascript engines and [DOMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document%5fObject%5fModel), allowing AJAX to occur.

Using this test script (it assumes you have Firefox installed; Selenium supports other browsers if needed):

```
# Import 3rd Party libraries
from selenium                                       import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class requester_firefox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.selenium_browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.selenium_browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)

    def __del__(self):
        self.selenium_browser.quit()
        self.selenium_browser = None

    def __call__(self, url):
        try:
            self.selenium_browser.get(url)
            the_page = self.selenium_browser.page_source
        except Exception:
            the_page = ""
        return the_page

test = requester_firefox()
print test("http://www.seek.com.au/jobs/in-australia/#dateRange=999&workType=0&industry=&occupation=&graduateSearch=false&salaryFrom=0&salaryTo=999999&salaryType=annual&advertiserID=&advertiserGroup=&keywords=police+check&page=1&isAreaUnspecified=false&location=&area=&nation=3000&sortMode=Advertiser&searchFrom=quick&searchType=").encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

It will load SEEK and wait for AJAX pages. The `encode` method is necessary (for me at least) because SEEK returns a unicode string which the Windows console seemingly can't print.

Comment: This is a bit of an awkward solution, but it seems that there really isn't a better one. It does work well though and for python 3 you don't need to encode it. 1 question though, do I need any prerequisites aside from the selenium package ? I already have selenium ide installed and I assume it is required since it does run off firefox, isn't it? Either way thanks a bunch mate !

Comment: The webdriver is different from the ide; so no, you don't need the ide installed for this to work. Just `easy_install` selenium.

Comment: don't use `__del__()` unless you have to. It complicates the reasoning about the code because it involves garbage collector. Use a context manager for a proper cleanup instead. It is easy to create one using `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, point taken. I found that when using Selenium, sometimes the web browser process wasn't killed upon object GC or deletion; so I had to make the `self.selenium_browser.quit()` explicit.

Comment: Python doesn't guarantee that `__del__` will be called at all. Use context manager to make sure that `quit` is called